# What is the name for an uppercut (scooping punch) in Japanese?

Tags: word-requests

Ura-zuki is more linear. Age Ura-zuki is rising but still linear.  What about Sukui ura-zuki?  Any martial artists know this one?
I am hoping for an official karate term, but I will settle for a gramatically correct term that describes a scooping punch (western boxing uppercut).
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I suspect this might be more appropriate on https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think it should stay. If this were originally posted on martialarts.se, I can imagine they'd consider sending it here. Heck, having it here in Japanese would require a Japanese speaker who happens to know martial arts, and having it in Martial Arts would require a martial artist who happens to know Japanese. Too many gray areas on the whole network...

Comment: Since the OP already knows what the term is in English and is looking for an equivalent in Japanese, I think it belongs here. On top of that, you don't _have_ to know martial arts to answer the question, as the answers show (but you'd probably have to know Japanese).

Answer (score 2):

I don't do karate or any other martial arts, but the basic term for this is katakana [アッパーカット](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88), which should be understood by almost everyone who is fluent in Japanese.

[裏拳 (ura-ken)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A3%8F%E6%8B%B3%E6%89%93%E3%81%A1) is more a like backhand blow, or a blow using the back of one's hand. This is well-known, too.

[裏突き (ura-zuki)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A3%8F%E7%AA%81%E3%81%8D-1460597) is a straight punch with the palm facing upward. I think it's a karate-specific term.

According to this [list of karate 突き](http://www.ichiyukai.com/lesson/lesson-c.html), it appears [鉤【かぎ】突【づ】き](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%89%A4%E7%AA%81%E3%81%8D) (kagi-zuki, 鉤 means 'hook') clearly says it's a 弧を描くような (=curved, arc-like) punch, but it's a punch blown horizontally. It looks like a karate jargon rather than a generic term, but I don't know the awareness of this term even among karate fans.

I haven't heard age ura-zuki (上げ裏突き?) or sukui ura-zuki (すくい裏突き?) and they're not listed in the linked list, either (these names look reasonable at least to me, though).

Comment: 裏突き is not a backhand, but a straight punch, like a 正拳突き, but with the hand "reversed" (i.e. with the palm facing upward).
鉤突き is a hook, as it comes from the side.

Comment: Right, 鉤突き is not a uppercut, edited my answer.

Comment: An anon tried to add the following as an edit to the answer post, but since it's more appropriate as a comment, I'll add it here: _"Excellent comments. While the Japanese Karate Association use the term ura-zuki for a back fist strike, it has often been interpreted and taught (in the West) as an uppercut. If one imagines throwing a baseball but turning the wrist such that the back of the fist strikes the opponent's face, that would be the application of ura-zuki."_

Answer (score 2):

I think the term you're looking for is [上げ突き]{あげつき}.  Though similar, it's not exactly the same move.

アッパーカット or アッパー are recognizable to any Japanese familiar with martial arts, too, as naruto has mentioned.